# Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: reactjs, reporting-services, cors

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/dreams/api/user/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

### *This project is a reactjs project. I was tired of looking at many YouTube videos and websites. I can't figure out how to apply express and cross method.*

**error message in user interface**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrM9k.png)

**API requst code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnDdN.png)

**This project is a reactjs project. I was tired of looking at many YouTube videos and websites. I can't figure out how to apply express and cross method. I need to skip the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" which cross the error message.**

Comment: The `http://127.0.0.1:8000` API is a nodeJS api? Has CORS been enabled on the server/nodeJS api?  If You are using ExpressJS, this article would be useful https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cors should be added to the backend:

```
npm install cors

var express = require('express')
var cors = require("cors")
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```